# How to scrape without web browser driver?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I made a web scrape program using selenium.
This program is access target URL and download a file.
After updating Chrome, program does not work because chromedriver is old version.

How to do web scraping and file download not use chromedriver?

Thank all for reading.

Comment: We can't say anything without seeing your existing code. That being said, @Kostas' answer sounds about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you also updated [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), that way your program would work again. Or you could install the previous Chrome version again.

But if you don't want that, you can use [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I fixed Chrome version for now and looking for not use selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can use a headless scrapper like [Pupeppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer). You also can update your Chrome driver to be compatible with your browser version that is the most recomended.